# How to get only process id that runs on specific port at Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

The following command let me list running process on specified port with some other options as follows:

```
   netstat -ano | findstr 9999
   TCP     127.0.0.1    0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING    26064
```

How would I edit the command to list only the PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `netstat` command doesn't have parameters allowing you to select the columns that are shown. So you might need some additional processing of the output. One way to achieve that is to use Powershell:

```
netstat -ano | findstr 9999 | Select-String "TCP\s+(.+)\:(.+)\s+(.+)\:(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)" | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.matches[0].Groups[6].value }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative way instead of using netstat to get the same result?